# segfault in system log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm seeing these kind of msgs in the system log

```
kernel: CLIDaemon[16777]: segfault at ece85260 ip 00000000ece85260 sp 00000000ffc8c64c error 14
```

I can't find out what is CLIDaemon, anyone out there that can help find out what it is that's segfaulting and find the source of the segfault

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps` to find out if this process with PID 16777 is still running. Use `/proc/16777/exe` to find the executable name for this process. `dpkg -S /full/path/to/exe` should show you the package name this executable belongs to. `apt show packagename` should show you the information about the package.